# Second computer gets slow connection when the first is connected as well

Tags: windows, internet

I have a router and an 8Mbit/s connection.

The router is connected to two computers via Ethernet ports.

The issue is that the first computer which runs Win 7 gets full speed, The second one which runs XP Pack 3 gets very low internet speed, like 2kb/s even though the first computer doesn't download anything at the moment.

So i tried to unplug the first computer and guess what, the second computer got the full speed.

I wonder why? Is there a setting that i'm not aware of in XP? I noticed that even the local router admin loads slowly unless as i said disconnect the other computers.

My router is Sagem3304.

P.S. I scanned both computers with updated antiviruses and nothing was found. I also tried WIFI and it didn't solve it.

Comment: This just sounds like a lousy router to me.

Comment: is the firmware on the router up to date?